# ASP.Net submit html code (encode-decode)

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc application and i want to submit an html code on post, i have a custom binder for this request, i have this html code that i submit in a editor

```
<div id="content-home-rect">
    <div class="rect-home"></div>
    <div class="rect-home"></div>
    <div class="rect-home"></div>
    <div class="rect-home"></div>
</div>
```

when i submit i got this

```
%3Cdiv%3E%26lt%3Bdiv%20id%3D%22content-home-rect%22%26gt%3B%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%26nbsp%3B%20%26nbsp%3B%20%26lt%3Bdiv%20class%3D%22rect-home%22%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fdiv%26gt%3B%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%26nbsp%3B%20%26nbsp%3B%20%26lt%3Bdiv%20class%3D%22rect-home%22%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fdiv%26gt%3B%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%26nbsp%3B%20%26nbsp%3B%20%26lt%3Bdiv%20class%3D%22rect-home%22%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fdiv%26gt%3B%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%26nbsp%3B%20%26nbsp%3B%20%26lt%3Bdiv%20class%3D%22rect-home%22%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Fdiv%26gt%3B%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%26lt%3B%2Fdiv%26gt%3B%3C%2Fdiv%3E
```

this is my custom binder

```
var req = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Unvalidated.Form;
var model = new ContenutiDetailModel();

foreach (var item in lingue)
{
  string html = req.Get("text-" + item);


   html = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode(html);


    var ol = new ObjectLingue();
       ol.content = html;
       ol.lingua = item;
       ol.id = req.Get("id-" + item);
       model.html.Add(ol);
}

return model;
```

the html decode give me back always the same string, i don't get why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you've provided appears to have been both HTML-encoded *and* URL-encoded. You will need to reverse both encoding operations to get the original string back.

It also appears to have extra `<div>` tags inserted. You will need to look at how the value is being posted to find out why.

**NB:** You don't need to go through `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server` to get to the `HtmlDecode` function; it's available on the static `HttpUtility` class.

```
string html = req.Get("text-" + item);
// %3Cdiv%3E%26lt%3Bdiv%20id%3D%22content-home-rect%22%26gt...

html = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(html);
// <div>&lt;div id="content-home-rect"&gt;</div>...

html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);
// <div><div id="content-home-rect"></div>...
```